# Cisco Prime Infrastructure 2.1 err-disabled notifications

Tags: cisco

On Cisco Works LMS we were able to receive notifications whenever one of our ports became err-disabled, however I am unable to configure this with Cisco Prime Infrastructure 2.1.  We are currently getting other messages from prime about our devices, so I know SNMP is configured correctly.

I raised the severity setting for "Security violation on an Interface" in system settings, but I still get nothing.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

Configure your devices to send SNMP Traps and Syslog messages when your ports become err-disabled and have your monitoring system collect these.